# X11 transparent window: click-through only where alpha = 0

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xcb

Can I have a window with alpha that I can click-through the 100% transparent portions of the window? I'm looking for a general solution not based on the shapes extension.

- In Windows this is done by setting WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.
- In OSX this is done by setting setIgnoresMouseEvents(true).
- In X11 this is done by ...?

Comment: see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121217-00/?p=5823

Comment: Write an abstraction layer to generate the mask automatically (according to you rules).

Answer (score 4):

The [X11 Nonrectangular Window Shape Extension](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xextproto/shape.html) is the answer you're looking for.

You may be getting confused by the description of this protocol as an "extension". X11 implements many features as extensions to the base protocol. It doesn't mean that these features are nonstandard or that they should be avoided; it just means they weren't part of X11 when it was released in 1987.

Comment: I don't have the problem with the fact that it's an extension, but with the fact that I have to define a bit mask for the entire window, which I have to redraw every time the window itself gets redrawn. So there isn't a more direct way like on Windows and OSX then?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Sorry. Keep in mind that, if you aren't using a compositing X server, the server needs to know what shape your window is to clip drawing on any windows under it. If it had to "ask" your application about each and every pixel drawn under your window, performance would be dismal.

Comment: You don't need to redraw mask when window content is updated, they are separate ( but might need to if its resized )

Comment: Since this is Stack Overflow a MWE would have been nice.